# Is the memory of a (character) array freed by going out of scope?

Tags: c, arrays, memory

Very much related to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322884/c-does-going-out-of-scope-like-this-free-the-associated-memory), but I found this to be a separate issue and am unable to find a solid answer to this.

Is the memory used by a (character) array freed by going out of scope?

An example:

```
void method1()
{
  char str[10];
  // manipulate str
}
```

So after the method1 call, is the memory used by str (10 bytes) freed, or do I need to explicitly call free on this as well?

My intuition tells me this is just a simple array of primitive types, so it's automatically freed. I'm in doubt because in C you can't assume anything to be automatically freed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In this case no you do not need to call free.  The value "str" is a stack based value which will be cleaned up when that particular method / scope is exited.

You only need to call free on values which are explicitly created via malloc.

Comment: (Where "no" means - yes, it's free'd by going out of scope, and no you don't need to call free explicitly)

Comment: @jmanning2k i re-read my post as well and editted it to be a bit more clear about what "no" meant

Answer (score 9):

It is automatically freed. If you didn't malloc it, you 
don't need to free it. But this has nothing to do with it being
a "simple array of primitive types" - it would be freed if it was
an array of structures. It is freed because it is a local variable.

Given that you are asking these very basic questions, 
I have to ask which C textbook are you using. Personally, I don't believe that you can usefully learn C without 
reading Kernighan & Ritchie's [The C Programming Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language_%28book%29), which
explains all this stuff very clearly.

Comment: I actually read (and studied) The C Programming Language by K&R, but that was some time ago and before I actually "got into" C myself a bit more.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is "freed." (Not free()'ed, though.)

Since str is an automatic variable, it will only last as long as its scope, which is until the end of the function block.

Note that you only free() what you malloc().

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the memory is freed automatically once `method1` returns.  The memory for `str` is allocated on the stack and is freed once the method's stack frame is cleaned up.  Compare this to memory allocated on the heap (via `malloc`) which you must explicitly free.

Answer (score 1):

No, local variables of this sort are allocated on the stack, so when you return from the procedure the memory is available for the next function call, which will use the memory for its stack frame.

If you use `malloc()` the space is allocated on the heap, which must be explicitly freed.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's freed not because it's primitives but that it's a local variable and that will be allocated on the stack not the heap. If you don't malloc it then you can't free it as far as I remember.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is "freed" when it goes out of scope.
No, you don't have to explicitly free it.

The char array is allocated on the stack, so when you return from the function, that stack space is re-usable.  You do not need to explicitly free the memory.

Good rule of thumb: if you `malloc`, you must `free`.

Comment: The question is about C, not C++

Comment: Ah, yes, indeed.  Let me fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit rusty in C/C++ lately, but I think you're right. As long as you didn't dynamically allocate that memory, you should be fine.