# Values in array change themselves

Tags: objective-c, arrays

This is probably a total noob question, but I just can't seem to figure this out by myself. I searched here and google, but didn't had any luck.

I have a class with some name, for instance, 'logme'. I implement a float *floaters in the .h file, make a property en synthesize it in the .m file. Two methods inside the .m file method1 and method2. When I perform method1 from the viewcontroller, it makes the floaters variable an array with some values. I NSLog them to check if they are and they are. After that I perform method2 which only NSLogs the same array but now the values in the array are totally different.

logme.h

```
@interface Logme : NSObject {
    float *floaters;
}
-(void)method1;
-(void)method2;
```

logme.m

```
@implementation Logme
-(void)method1 {
    floaters = (float[8]) {
        1.0f, 2.0f,
        3.0f, 4.0f,
        6.0f, 5.0f,
        7.0f, 8.0f,
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        NSLog(@"%f", floaters[i]);
    }
}
-(void)method2 {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        NSLog(@"%f", floaters[i]);
    }
}
@end
```

Calling the methods from viewcontroller:

```
logme = [Logme alloc];
[logme method1];
[logme method2];
```

Outcome:

```
NSLog from method1:
1.000000
2.000000
3.000000
4.000000
6.000000
5.000000
7.000000
8.000000

NSLog from method2:
0.000000
-1.998885
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
```

- I'm sorry. I was fighting this 4 spaces system. It wouldn't let me add the .m file code. Finally got it in here :)

Comment: Your question isn't answerable without some (minimal) code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Can you please add method1 and method2 implementation? How is it changing? Are you creating different objects for Logme? And how are you calling method1 and method2? can you post that as well?

Comment: `floaters = (float[8]) ...` isn't creating a persistent array -- it goes "poof" when the method returns.

Comment: why don't you use NSArray or NSMutableArray? They are so much more powerful and easy than a C array

Comment: @userXXXX you need to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335230/is-the-memory-of-a-character-array-freed-by-going-out-of-scope) and learn a lot.

Comment: I'm going to give my little sermon here about how Objective-C is a lousy "first" language.  One should at least learn the rudiments of C/C++ first, in addition to having some more substantial programming experience perhaps with C or with Java.  Starting with Objective-C you'll learn a lot of bad habits and will never quite understand what you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are assigning a pointer to a block of memory that is in the stack, this means that when you exit from mrthod1 that memory will be deallocated.The value printed after method1 are casual, it may also happen that the memory gets not touched, but usually the stack changes at every method call, so that's your case.

**Choice 1**

You are using floaters as an array, so declare it to be an array and it will have it's own storage:

```
@interface Logme : NSObject {
float floaters[8];
}

-(void)method1 {
    for(int i=0; i<8;i++)
        floaters[i]=i+1;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    NSLog(@"%f", floaters[i]);
}
```

**Choice 2**

Let floaters be a pointer, but allocate dinamically the memory for floaters:

```
-(void)method1 {
floaters=(float*)malloc(8*sizeof(float));
for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
    floaters[i]=i+1;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    NSLog(@"%f", floaters[i]);
}
```

And don't forget to free the memory when you don't need it anymore.

Comment: I thank you very much for this explanation with examples. I understand what I was doing wrong and how to do it the right way.

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer was given by @HotLicks in the comments. I thought I'd give a little bit more of an explanation.

When you have something like this in a method:

```
- (void)someMethod {
    float *numbers = (float[8]) {
        1.0f, 2.0f,
        3.0f, 4.0f,
        6.0f, 5.0f,
        7.0f, 8.0f,
    };
}  // <-- end of scope for these values
```

the memory for the values is put into a special area of memory called the stack. This memory stays in place only as long as the values are in scope. In other words, when the closing curly brace for the code block is reached, the stack and its memory goes away.

In your case, you are assigning this block of stack memory to an instance variable. So when the end of the block is reached and the stack values go away, the instance variable is left pointing to the same memory location. But the values are no longer there. That memory space has probably been reused for something else.

This is why the second method prints out different values. You are trying to accessing the 8 float values from the same memory but the memory has been reused for something else.

There are a few possible solutions. You could use `malloc` to allocate memory for the array and copy the values into that memory space (and later release the memory with `free`). Or you could use an `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray`.