# Why do we need to cast what malloc returns?

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory

```
    int length = strlen(src);
    char *structSpace = malloc(sizeof(String) + length + 1);
    String *string = (String*) structSpace;    
    int *string = (int*) structSpace;
```

*I created a struct called String

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages, this looks like C, removing the C++ tag from the question would clarify it for potential answerers.

Comment: What exactly is "String" then?

Comment: `String *` doesn't look like C to me, but it's clearly confusing in more ways than just that.

Comment: *sorry, I created a Struct called String

Comment: You have two string variables...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't. `void*` will implicitly cast to whatever you need in C. See also the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html) on why you would want to explicitly avoid casting malloc's return in C. @Sinan's answer further illustrates why this has been followed inconsistently.

Comment: Correct, you shouldn't be using malloc in C++.

Comment: This is the typical response, but I don't completely agree. Sure, if you have a braindead compiler it might let you get away without including `stdlib.h`, but there are some cases where you can let the compiler check your work.  See my comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322884/does-going-out-of-scope-like-this-free-the-associated-memory/1322898#1322898

Answer (score 6):

Because malloc returns a pointer to void, i.e., it is simply allocating chunks of memory with no regard as to the data that will be stored there.  In C++ your returned void* will not be implicitly cast to the pointer of your type.  In your example, you have not cast what malloc has returned.  Malloc returned a void* which was implicitly cast to a char*, but on the next line you... ok, it doesn't make much sense anymore.

Comment: Now your code doesn't make sense. Two variables called `string`? What are you really trying to ask?

Comment: To be clear, you do not have to and shouldn't really cast the return value of `malloc()` in the C programming language. This is related to an old problem that was an issue before C90. I think the original question might have been tagged as C++ and not C, for which the behavior is different as the answerer stated.

Answer (score 6):

The C FAQ list is an invaluable resource: [Why does some code carefully cast the values returned by malloc to the pointer type being allocated?](http://c-faq.com/malloc/cast.html).

Answer (score 4):

This is one of the few issues that makes the statement "C++ is a superset of C" not completely true.  In C, a `void` pointer can be implicitly cast to any other type of pointer.  However, C++ is a bit more strict with type safety, so you need to explicitly cast the return value of `malloc` to the appropriate type.  Usually, this isn't much of an issue, because C++ code tends to use `new` rather than `malloc`, which doesn't require typecasting.

Answer (score 3):

In C, casting the result from malloc is unnecessary and should not be done. Doing so can, for example, cover up the error of having failed to `#include <stdlib.h>`, so you don't have a prototype for malloc in scope. This, in turn, can lead to other errors and lack of portability (though the worst offenders in that respect are now mostly obsolete).

In C++, you must cast the result of malloc to assign it to a pointer to any type other than void. Unless you really *need* to write code that can be compiled as either C or C++, however, you should generally avoid using `malloc` in C++ at all and allocate memory using `new`.

Answer (score 1):

You tend to see this kind of C code from novices (or C++ coders :-) ):

```
int main() {
    int len = 40;
    char *my_string = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*len);
    return 0;
}
```

This is unnecessary and evil, you can avoid the useless cast via including `stdlib.h`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    int len = 40;
    char *my_string = malloc(sizeof(char)*len);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you really want a `sizeof` use `char *my_string = malloc(sizeof(*my_string)*len);` so that the RHS remains correct even if the LHS changes. Otherwise, note that `sizeof(char)` is always `1`.

Comment: BTW, if you don't #include <stdlib.h>, the code is incorrect, because malloc() without prototype returns an int, and pointer values might not be representable by an int (undefined behavior...)

Answer (score -1):

You should strongly consider casting after using the malloc command because it provides for greater portability and greater compatibility with other parts of your program. If you do not do so, you may run the risk of incompatible data types which could result in errors.