# What's the error with fgets in this code?

Tags: c, pointers, fgets

Where am I going wrong and why?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
char *str;
int length, i, j, flag = 0;

printf("\n\nEnter string: ");
fgets(str, 20, stdin);
printf("You entered: %s", str);
    return 0;
}
```

There's a problem with the line `fgets(str, 20, stdin);` line. I cannot figure it out. After entering the string, the compiler just stops working and I get an error saying: **This program has stopped working**. Could you point where am I going wrong and also a workaround for this problem? The standard library defines `fgets` as:

```
char * fgets ( char * str, int num, FILE * stream );
```

I'm using *Sublime Text 2* and *GCC on the MinGW shell*.

A different question based on the pointer concept:
Are there any differences between `char * str`, `char* str` and `char *str`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So answering my own question, the code which I posted throws up an error because I am not allocating memory for the variable named `str`. I am just giving it an arbitrary memory location.

So for the above code to work correctly, we can either allocate memory on the stack or heap.

For allocating on the stack, use `char str[20]` and for allocating memory on the heap, use `char *str = malloc(20)` or `char *str = malloc(20*sizeof(char))`.

***Do not worry too much about the details if you don't know about stack or heap. Any of them will do for simple console programs.***

As to my other question, the position of `*` in `char* str`, `char * str` and `char *str` does not matter. All 3 of them are the same.

Another question that I asked in association with @P0W's answer was why we aren't casting the memory address that is returned by `malloc` in `char *str = malloc(20*sizeof(char))`.
The answer to this question is that it's not necessary and should be avoided in C. Include the `stdlib.h` header file to get a workaround .

Check this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634153/why-do-we-need-to-typecast-what-malloc-returns) for more details. Or you can also view the [C FAQ section](http://c-faq.com/malloc/cast.html).

Comment: One can also use _global_ memory as in `static char str[20]`.  Typically this is rightfully frowned upon, but it is viable option in select cases.

Comment: @ash9209, casting the returned value of `malloc` helps the next programmer who reads your code.  When`stdlib.h` is included there is no technical downside to explicitly casting `malloc`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to allocate memory for `str`

Any size say 128.

`char *str = malloc(128*sizeof(char));`

or

`char str[128];`

Comment: One more question: Why don't we have to typecast **(char*)** before **malloc** here?

Comment: @ash9209 `malloc` return type is `void *`. It is implicitly converted to another pointer type, so its unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't allocated any memory for `str`.  Replace `char *str` with `char *str = malloc(20);` for heap allocation or `char str[20]` for stack allocation.

It doesn't matter where you place the `*` - all three statements are identical.

P.S. Sublime Text 2 is just a text editor, and which text editor you use has no effect on the program.  The compiler and OS do matter, though.

Comment: It's showing a warning when I add the malloc function: **In function 'main': warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ' malloc' [enabled by default]**

Comment: Add the line `#include <stdlib.h>` at the top of your program.

Comment: Yeah I know it isn't necessary to mention the text editor. But being on stackoverflow for quite a while, and browsing through many questions, some idiots do ask about the editor too. I don't know what they get out of it, though.