# Why do we cast return value of malloc?

Tags: c, malloc

Could someone explain to me why do some programmers use (char*) in front of the malloc? I know that it returns void but why do I want it to return just char memory? I'm sorry, I'm just a newbie in programming. Thank you

Comment: I think you mean (char*), not (*char).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634153/why-do-we-need-to-typecast-what-malloc-returns

Comment: "What's dangerous about casting result of malloc()?":
http://stackoverflow.com/q/1565496/1150918

Comment: Here is an amazing post about the same subject : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No need to cast return value of `malloc` as its return type is `void*`.

> Can someone explain why do some programmers use `(char *)` in front of the malloc?

They are doing wrong (most probably) by casting it (in good programmers opinion).

As **[wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation)** says:

`malloc` returns a void pointer (`void *`), which indicates that it is a pointer to a region of unknown data type. **The use of casting is required in C++ due to the strong type system, whereas this is not the case in C**<sub>1</sub>. The lack of a specific pointer type returned from `malloc` is type-unsafe behavior according to some programmers: `malloc` allocates based on byte count but not on type. This is different from the C++ [`new` operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_(C%2B%2B)) that returns a pointer whose type relies on the operand.
One may "cast" this pointer to a specific type:

```
int *ptr;
ptr = malloc(10 * sizeof (*ptr));               /* without a cast */
ptr = (int *)malloc(10 * sizeof (*ptr));        /* with a cast */
ptr = reinterpret_cast<int *>(malloc(10 * sizeof (*ptr))); /* with a cast, for C++ */
```

**There are advantages and disadvantages to performing such a cast**.

### Advantages to casting:

> - Including the cast allows a program or function to **compile as C++**.
> - The cast allows for pre-1989 versions of `malloc` that originally returned a `char *`.
> - Casting can help the developer identify inconsistencies in type sizing should the destination pointer type change, particularly if the pointer is declared far from the `malloc()` call.

### Disadvantages to casting:

> - Under the ANSI C standard, the cast is **redundant**.
> - **Adding the cast may mask failure to include the header `stdlib.h`, in which the prototype for `malloc` is found**. In the absence of a prototype for `malloc`, the standard requires that the C compiler assume `malloc` returns an int. If there is no cast, a warning is issued when this integer is assigned to the pointer; however, with the cast, this warning is not produced, hiding a bug. On certain architectures and data models (such as LP64 on 64-bit systems, where long and pointers are 64-bit and int is 32-bit), this error can actually result in undefined behavior, as the implicitly declared `malloc` returns a 32-bit value whereas the actually defined function returns a 64-bit value. Depending on calling conventions and memory layout, this may result in stack smashing. This issue is less likely to go unnoticed in modern compilers, as they uniformly produce warnings that an undeclared function has been used, so a warning will still appear. For example, GCC's default behavior is to show a warning that reads "incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function" regardless of whether the cast is present or not.
> - If the type of the pointer is changed, one must fix all code lines where `malloc` was called and cast (unless it was cast to a `typedef`).

---

<sub>1. Emphases are mine.</sub>

Comment: Your last point may or may not actually be a disadvantage.  If the type of the pointer might be changed in a fashion that would require inspecting all the places that allocate it (e.g. because the size might need to be adjusted), the fact that the lines with `malloc` would need to be changed could be a good thing.

Comment: @supercat; Yes it could be a good thing but at the same time it could be pathetic.

Comment: A better way to make sure the proper type is used for `sizeof` in the call to `malloc()` is simply *not* using a type at all, but an expression: `sizeof *pointer` is less error-prone. And thus the third "advantage" is negated.

Answer (score 3):

As the return type of malloc is void*, when you assign the result to a pointer, it is converted implicitly to the new type. So, there is no need for explicit casting. Actually, using an explicit cast is discouraged, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 2):

**malloc** returns **void***, which is a generic pointer that can point to any type of data. The **(char*)** is an explicit type conversion, converting the pointer returned by malloc from a pointer to anything, to a pointer to char. This is unnecessary in C, since it is done implicitly, and it is actually recommended not to do this, since it can hide some errors.

If you need the code to compile as C++ too, and not just as C, you will however need the explicit conversion, since C++ doesn't perform the implicit conversion.

Answer (score 0):

`malloc()` return a `void*`, as `malloc()` does not know how its caller will be using the memory it allocated on the heap.
So it's up to you, the caller to cast the `(void*)`, into the appropriate type of pointer, that you want to use inside the memory. 
`(int*)` to store integers.
`(char*)` to store characters etc..

Having said so, you don't have to explicitly cast the return of a `malloc()` call. And in some cases, doing so may result in bugs.

Kindly read up the issue here

[What's wrong with casting malloc's return value?](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html)

[Specifically, what's dangerous about casting the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565496/specifically-whats-dangerous-about-casting-the-result-of-malloc?lq=1)