# How do I take dynamic array using malloc function in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I want to take dynamic array in my program.
I have used `malloc` function. In my system there is total 32 relays are present. 
At a time there will be 12 relays will be off max. But in worst case it can be 32.

so I have taken `size = 32` in my program. therefore i need to enter 32 values every time while testing. I want to take only 12 values at a time in array.

This is my code..

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    void main(){

    int  relay_check[]={0},i;
    int *relay_check1;
    const int  size=32;

    relay_check1 = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)* size);

    for(i = 0;i < size ; i++ )
       {
           scanf("%d",&relay_check[i]); 
           /*relay_check[i] is the content of element at index i and &relay_check[i] is the         address of element 
     at index i */
    }
     if (!relay_check) { /* If data == 0 after the call to malloc, allocation failed  for some reason */
    perror("Error allocating memory");
    abort();
    }

    for( i = 1;i < size ; ++i) {
    printf("relay_check [%d]: %d\n", i, relay_check[i]);
    }
    for(i=1;i<9;i++){
        if(i == relay_check[i] )
            printf("0");
        else
            printf("1");
    }

    printf("\n");

    for(i=9;i<17;i++){
        if(i == relay_check[i] )
            printf("0");
        else
            printf("1");
    }

    printf("\n");

    for(i=17;i<25;i++){
        if(i == relay_check[i] )
            printf("0");
        else
            printf("1");
    }

    printf("\n");

    for(i=25;i<33;i++){
        if(i == relay_check[i] )
            printf("0");
        else
            printf("1");
    }
    printf("\n");

    getch();
    }
```

**so what else changes i need to do?**

Comment: this `int  relay_check[]={0}` declaration stores only one value. You need to find space to store other 31 values separately.

Comment: delete `relay_check[]={0},` and rename `relay_check1` to `relay_check`. also `if (!relay_check) {` too late.

Answer (score 0):

`int  relay_check[]={0};` means that you are allocating space for only one integer and initializing it to `0` and hence

```
for(i = 0;i < size ; i++ )
{
   scanf("%d",&relay_check[i]); 
}
```

this will invoke **undefined behavior**. Declare `relay_check` as

```
 int  relay_check[32]={0};
```

And also [no need to cast the return value of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20094422/2455888).

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to sum up what you need to change in you code :

- when declaring `relay_check` you either give the exact size and initialize it later or explicitly initializing it without giving the size.

  *- the exact size : `int relay_check[32]`

  *- initializing without giving size : `int relay_check[] = {1 , 45 , 7 , ... , 47} // the whole 32 elements`

  *- OR (I think this is what you wanted to do ) give the exact size and initialize all the elements to 0s: `int relay_check[32] = {0}`
- error checking concerning `malloc` need to be done immediately after calling it
- after `scanf()` add a `getchar()` so that it receives the trailing newline character